# How to use a var value in place of a css property in a jQuery ".css()" method

Tags: jquery

I've got this :

```
$('.something').css({ 'margin-left' : '100px'});
```

Sometimes it needs to be changed to this :

```
$('.something').css({ 'right' : '100px'});
```

So I've been trying to put this in a string var as follow :

```
var css_prprty = 'margin-left';
if(change_needed){
    css_prprty = 'right';
}

$('.something').css({ css_prprty : '100px'});
```

It fails. 
And for some reason it seems logical that it does, but I can't think of a way to resolve this.

Anyone know what would be the proper way to use a variable value in this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a simple solution :

```
$('.something').css(css_prprty,'100px');
```

---

Now, let's talk about the more general problem of building an object with a dynamic property name. You can't do it in one go, as a literal, you must do it in two steps :

```
var obj = {};
obj[css_prprty] = '100px';
$('.something').css(obj);
```

*(as Oriol points it, there will be a shortcut in ES6)*

Comment: because OP is passing the CSS property as object.. :)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Well, you can't, today, build a literal object with a dynamic property name. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers

Comment: @dystroy You can, if you use a browser that supports ES6 computed property names, like Firefox 34.

Comment: I had already managed with you're fisrt solution, but it becomes à problem when you have more than one property to update.

Comment: That said, I wasn't aware of that object building thing. That's what i was after. This is very helpfull, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because `css_property` is an `IdentifierName`, so the resulting property name is its [`StringValue`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-identifier-names-static-semantics-stringvalue). Therefore, the following codes are equivalent:

```
var obj = { css_prprty : '100px'};
var obj = { "css_prprty" : '100px'};
```

Before EcmaScript 6, there is no way to use variables as property names when creating an object literal. You must create the object first, and then set the properties, using bracket notation:

```
var obj = {};
obj[css_prprty] = '100px';
```

EcmaScript 6 introduces computed property names, which allow you to do

```
var obj = { [css_prprty] : '100px'};
```

However, browser support is currently negligible.

For further information about how object literals are evaluated, see [Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation).